# Calculating Path Probabilities in VBA, using Binomial Tree Model

Tags: vba, excel, probability

for my master thesis I want to price a CVR (kind of exotic derivative) using different models. 
I am stuck with my binomial tree model, as I want to calculate the sum of all probabilities that lead to the "green zone" (find a link with a screenshot of the model) For example if I go up 8 nodes with probability pu and 4 times down with probability (1-pu) I will get to the upper bound of the "green zone". The probability for this path is 0.06%. Now I want to calculate the sum of all probabilities that end up in the green zone.

I know there is a binom.dist and combin function in excel but I do not exactly know how to adopt this to my problem since the probabilities are time varying (1st probability for going up can be found in cell C12).

The binomial tree is set up as follows:

Cell B31 is the starting point, C32 is one step up, C30 is one step down. In total the binomial tree has 12 time steps, leading to 90 nodes.

[image: Binomial Model]

Comment: it would help to show row numbers and column letters. Is 5.72 in b31? And to give a fully worked example of the 0.06% path.

Comment: VBA seems needed. What have you tried?

Comment: @JohnColeman to be honest, I haven't tried VBA so far because I have no idea how to set up a index that has the restriction to end up in the green zone....

Comment: @QHarr I added another screenshot that includes the row and columns. You get the probability of the path by multiplying the probabilities of going up 8 times  with 4 times the probability of going down. (8*pu*4*pd) = 0.06%

Comment: What are the path rules? Normal tree I.e. can’t go backwards?

Comment: @QHarr, you can calculate the probabilities backwards as well (I guess) to end up in T=0 (first node). But it is indeed a normal binomial tree. With changing up and down probabilities every year (as time steps are quarterly, the probability changes every 4 nodes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a VBA function which computes all path probabilities in a binomial tree. You would need to link it with your spreadsheet and extract the values that you need. The code is based on the basic recurrence relation which defines Pascal's triangle:

```
Function BTree(probs As Variant) As Variant
    'Given a vector of probabilities of successes
    'One for each level of the tree,
    'returns a 0-based vector consisting of
    'path probabilities
    'the ith element is the probability
    'corresponding to i successes in the path

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    Dim Level As Long
    Dim cLevel As Variant, nLevel As Variant 'current and next level
    Dim s As Double, f As Double 'success/failure probs

    n = UBound(probs) - LBound(probs) + 1
    Level = 0
    ReDim nLevel(0 To 0) As Double
    nLevel(0) = 1  'root prob at level 0

    For i = LBound(probs) To UBound(probs)
        Level = Level + 1
        cLevel = nLevel
        ReDim nLevel(0 To Level)
        s = probs(i)
        f = 1 - s
        nLevel(0) = f * cLevel(0)
        nLevel(Level) = s * cLevel(Level - 1)
        For j = 1 To Level - 1
            nLevel(j) = s * cLevel(j - 1) + f * cLevel(j)
        Next j
    Next i
    BTree = nLevel
End Function
```

Tested like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim probs As Variant, result As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    probs = Array(0.7058, 0.7162, 0.7162, 0.7162, 0.7201, 0.7201, 0.7201, 0.7201, 0.7201, 0.7229, 0.7229, 0.7229)
    result = BTree(probs)
    For i = LBound(result) To UBound(result)
        Debug.Print result(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Output:

```
2.45812470386415E-07 
7.53656411298726E-06 
1.05902304943039E-04 
9.01850252454559E-04 
5.18379755707418E-03 
2.11875025735083E-02 
0.063142073263539 
0.138243496651607 
0.220687443705805 
0.250511742599513 
0.191938571395668 
8.91235060000786E-02 
1.89663313192269E-02
```

You would want the elements at indices in the range 4 to 8. Note that your 6% probability is incorrect. You would have a product of 12 numbers (one for each level) not 4 numbers (8*pu*4*pd). The probability of that particular path is much smaller than 6%.